# Same indentation for LOF, LOT and LOA

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries, acronyms

I am trying to format my list of tables and list of abbreviations in the same way, such that the indentation of the acronyms is the same as the indentation of table references. However, I had no luck even when using a different glossary style, like long.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,array}

\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,nomain,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\include{glossary}
%\setglossarystyle{long}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{SNA}{SNA}{some nice acronym}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[title={List of Abbreviations},type=\acronymtype]
\listoftables 

\begin{longtable}{|l|}
    \hline
    ... \\ \hline
    \caption{Some nice table}
    \label{tbl:table1}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: An example.]

Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. See the package `tocloft` please and the `\cfttabindent` length (which is most likely to be set to `0em`). Please don't use `\include` in the preamble! Use `\input` or `\loadglsentries`. Your example does not use any of your defined glossary or acronym entries!

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response and the additional hints which I'll keep in mind.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tocloft` and `\setlength{cfttabindent}{0em}` which will reduce the indentation of `table` entries to `0em`, so there is no indentation at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,array}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,nomain,nopostdot]{glossaries}

\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0em}

%\include{glossary}
%\setglossarystyle{long}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{SNA}{SNA}{some nice acronym}

\begin{document}
\gls{SNA}
\printglossary[title={List of Abbreviations},type=\acronymtype]
\listoftables 

\begin{longtable}{|l|}
    \hline
    ... \\ \hline
    \caption{Some nice table}
    \label{tbl:table1}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if the table number goes to two digits, the numbers will still be left aligned.  the original design allowed the numbers to be mutually right-aligned.  just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use package `tocbasic` (part of KOMA-Script bundle):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,array}

\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,nomain,nopostdot]{glossaries}
%\include{glossary}
%\setglossarystyle{long}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{SNA}{SNA}{some nice acronym}

\usepackage{tocbasic}[2016/06/14]
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0pt]{tocline}{table}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[title={List of Abbreviations},type=\acronymtype]
\listoftables 

\begin{longtable}{|l|}
    \hline
    ... \\ \hline
    \caption{Some nice table}
    \label{tbl:table1}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or if you are using a KOMA-Script class like in [your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/350072/43317):

```
\documentclass[oneside,
    listof=totoc% <- all list titles goes to TOC
]{scrbook}[2016/06/14]
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0pt]{tocline}{table}

\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,nomain,nopostdot,
    toc% <- added
]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{SNA}{SNA}{some nice acronym}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoftables
    \printglossary[title={List of Abbreviations},type=\acronymtype]
    \chapter{Chapter One}
    \gls{SNA}
    \captionof{table}{A table caption}
\end{document}
```

[image]