# Vertical space between LOF and LOA

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries, acronyms, tocloft

After Christian has helped me to solve my prior problem ([Same indentation for LOF, LOT and LOA](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350056/same-indentation-for-lof-lot-and-loa) - I assumed that this is a new issue and created another question), I am now faced with the situation that it seems that there is a different vertical space between the chapter text of the list of figures and the list of abbreviations.

I've created the following MWE for this case ([oneside]{scrbook} is required by the template I have to stick to and tocloft originates from Christian's solution):

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,nomain,nopostdot]{glossaries}

\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0em}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{SNA}{SNA}{some nice acronym}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}  
    \listoftables
    \clearpage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}
    \printglossary[title={List of Abbreviations},type=\acronymtype]
    \gls{SNA}
\end{document}
```

It seems to be best visible in following picture:

[image: An example]

Am I missing something here?
Thank you very much again all!

Comment: `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`

Comment: With a KOMA-Script class you can use its possibilies to format the LOT and LOF. You can also replace the manually entries in TOC by the class-option `listof=totoc` and the glossaries option `toc`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350093/43317